# jquery ajax data from function

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to retrieve data from a jQuery function.

Here is my function

```
function getPageHTML() {
    $("input").each(function(){
        $(this).attr("value", $(this).val());
    });
    return "<html>" + $("html").html() + "</html>";
}
```

above I am getting everything inside my 2 `<html>` and `</html>` tags with all values inside my inputs.

```
function send(){
    $.ajax({
        url:"save-script.php",
        type:'POST',
        data: getPageHTML()
    });
}
```

Above I am trying to send this data to my `save-script.php` file. This all works fine but it seems jQuery is interpreting certain character and symbols. The + and the & here.

```
function getPageHTML() {
    $("input").each(function(){
        $(this).attr("value", $(this).val());
    });
    return "<html>"   $("html").html()   "</html>";
}
```

my code ends up looking like this after executing the send function. 
I have tried using `dataType: "html"` with no success.

also tried `data: encodeURIComponent(getPageHTML())` but this ends up removing all my html.

I am trying to keep all these symbols and not have jQuery interpret these symbols.

Comment: First store return of `getPageHTML` into a variable & then pass that variable as ajax data.

Comment: Can you tell us what you're trying to accomplish? It's not really clear to me what you're trying to do from your code.

Comment: yes. every concatenated are missed out. I am just trying to copy my html without any interpretation. I have read about Jquery dataType but this doesn't work out if I use html

Comment: It's unclear what is the problem. How is the result of `getPageHTML()` look like and what's wrong with it?

Comment: getPageHTML() is simply getting everything inside my 2 html tags. when using the ajax function, I am missing out symbols such as the + and the &. all other html seems fine

Comment: Maybe it's nothing to do with your AJAX request, but in your `save-script.php`. @Adrien Boufflet - How you try to retrieved save data? Is it in file or database?

Comment: paul-tomkiel my php file couldn't be easier. <?php
 print_r($_POST);
?>

Answer (score 1):

You will want to save the output of `getPageHtml()` to a variable like so:

`var html = getPageHtml();`

Then pass that new variable as the data of the AJAX call.

```
var html = getPageHtml();

function send(data){

    $.ajax({
        url:"save-script.php",
        type:'POST',
        data: data
    });
}

send(html);
```

Try this and let me know if it works.

Comment: Yes I had already tried that one out but I get "getPageHtml is not defined".

Comment: Same problem. if I put my variable outside my function, it doesn't seem to find it.

Comment: @AdrienBoufflet Perhaps post your updated code to a jsbin or something so I can help you debug.  What I have posted here should work with no problems

Comment: yes. I will try and set up a fiddle to show my problem

Comment: silly me. I am sending a request with ajax to a .php file. this isn't possible with jsffidle if I am right?

Comment: @AdrienBoufflet not unless you have that php file uploaded to a server and you point to it at that location :)

Comment: yes but unfortunately this is running on my localhost :(

Comment: It doesn't matter if the URL it posts to actually exists. We can still examine the request in the chrome debugger or something similar. Here: http://jsfiddle.net/k6zdd3a6/
Compare what gets logged in the console with the network request: http://i.imgur.com/8RI0nKG.png
They look the same to me...

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to turn off encoding, this might be a good option:

> **processData** (default: `true`)
>
> Type: Boolean
>
> By default, data passed in to the data option as an object (technically, anything other than a string) will be processed and transformed into a query string, fitting to the default content-type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". **If you want to send a DOMDocument, or other non-processed data, set this option to `false`**.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

```
$.ajax({
    url:"save-script.php",
    type:'POST',
    processData: false,
    data: getPageHTML()
});
```

Comment: thanx for the response but doesn't seem to work. ajax is still interpreting certain symbols and characters.  work around was using   .replace(new RegExp( "\\+", "g" ),"%2B").replace(new RegExp( "\\&", "g" ),"%26"    but this doesn't solve my problem. if I try and copy the copied page, the symbols will have been replaced

Comment: I think it's the $.html call that's doing the escaping, not $.ajax

Comment: I have tried executing the function with a simple onclick="console.log(getPageHTML()); and all is fine. I get everything inside my 2 html tags without any encoding

Comment: it  is the $.ajax that is encoding certain characters or more like not interpreting these characters. If I execute the PageHTML() function, all characters and symbols are shows in my console log since I am using $("html").html(). the encoding happens when $.ajax is sent.

Answer (score 0):

First store return of `getPageHTML` into a variable & then pass that variable as ajax data.

Your `send` function should be like this:

```
function send(){
 var myHTML = getPageHTML();
    $.ajax({
    url:"save-script.php",
    type:'POST',
    data: myHTML
    });
}
```

Please note that `getPageHTML` should be defined before `send` function.

Answer (score 0):

Ok well it seems that I figured out a solution to my problem. I was unable to work my way around with `$.ajax` and what I was trying to do seemed quiet simple. Send a ajax `data:` to a .php file. My work around to all this actually made thing a little easier ;)

```
function send(){
    $.post("save-script.php",
   { getPageHTML }
 );
}
```

Hope this helps